# Calculating Time Complexity for school

Tags: java, time, time-complexity

I'm learning time complexity, and i'v been asked to write this method:
public static boolean findValWhat(int[][] m, int val)
that checks if val exist in m, and the method has to run in O(n) time, while "n" represents the rows in the array. is it even possible or logical?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. On topic and how to ask apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service. http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Seems like a not-unreasonable question about the nature of complexity measurements, although it IS one of those I would not answer with code being as I try to avoid actually doing people's homework for them.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what your method has to do.  If it's not specified then you just need to write a method that visits each column once (like print out the first entry in each column).

If your columns had a fixed number of rows (or you just visit a fixed number of rows for each column), you could visit every entry in the table since it would always grow by the same amount per column (making it linear).

I SUPPOSE if you HAD to make a method that was O(N) and HAD to visit every entry it's doable by WASTING time to make short columns take as long as long columns (which is such a bizarre concept that it's hurting my head)

EDIT:

One answer your instructor might want is to do it with a single loop over all rows.  This could be done by loading each row into a hash set and then looking up the value in the hash set.  This is NOT O(n) (it's O(n log n) at best) but it would only have one loop and from a naïve point of view that might qualify as O(n).

HOWEVER, strangely, if you are always passed an array with the same number of columns then ANY solution will be O(n), but will require nested loops!  This seems counter-intuitive but it's likely something I'd do if I were a teacher and wanted to demonstrate that complexity measurements didn't really mean anything.  (Since O(n) doesn't say how long n takes!  It could be that each n is 1 hour, but as long as n=2 takes 2 hours, and n=4 takes 4 hours it's still O(n))

Edit:

I'm not sure exactly what your teacher is after.  If there is a constant number of columns then the loop would be for(.. i < n..) { for(..i < c..))  If c is a constant then increases in n would be linear even with a second loop I believe, but that's a little tricky.

The other thing I could imagine is that they are looking for something like:

```
Create a HashSet

for(.. i < nRows ..)
{
   add each row to HashSet...
}

return haseset.contains(val);
```

Now this solution is actually o(n^2) I think (With an O(log n) thrown in for good measure), but since it only has one VISIBLE loop it might look like o(n)

So I'm not sure exactly what your teacher is after.

Here's another thing that LOOKS like it O(n):

```
Arrays.stream(m).flatMapToInt(x -> Arrays.stream(x)).forEach(
    a->if(a == val...));
```

When your teacher tells me what they were after, I'd love to know.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my thread. the method signature is:
public static boolean findValWhat(int[][] m, int val)
and I have to search val in m at a O(n)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I really don't need code I just want to get the basics that I feel I haven't been taught. I'm a little bit confused cause in every source I check it's says that your last example will be Quad. 
Like this text from StackOverflow:

for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
  for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
    statement;
}

**Is quadratic**. The running time of the two loops is proportional to the square of N. When N doubles, the running time increases by N * N.

Comment: Thank you again for all the great help! 
We indeed struggle at understanding the staff.

Comment: Update: So the staff have fixed their mistake and now the array is sorted. each row has also bigger values the the former, like this:
[25] [26] [27] [28] [29] [30] [31] row 3
[17] [18] [19] [21] [22] [23] [24] row 2
[9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] row 1
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] row 0

I wrote a method that runs as a BinarySearch on the last columns of the rows. if the last column is bigger then val, I check if the last column of the former row is smaller then val. that means I only need to BinarySearch once more, specifically on the current row.

Is it 2log n... not sure